# Spring JPA. Calling a stored procedure on INSERT

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

This is basically the question of `@GeneratedValue` but for a NON PRIMARY KEY.

I have a function, let it be `createToken()` stored in DB, which I would like to call during Spring JPA/Hibernate `repository.save(myAwesomeObject)`. Or even a sequence...

As I've said, I want it to be executed when an entity gets persisted/inserted.

And I want it to be visible in my java code.

The only thing that I've come up with is to have the

```
field1 varchar(255) not null default myfunc()
```

defined in the DDL.

It works, but:
a) see this as a solution "when there are no good ideas"
b) this isn't reflected (a part from a comment) in the `@Entity`
c) doing `repository.save(...)` returns the entity with that field as null (while the ID field is set), for which I need to basically make a second db call to get the actual entity. I do understand that if to switch on the DB, one would see that Hibernate's persist is far from one DB call, but every step of this solution smells like a workaround. And I don't enjoy my code being a "meh, it will have to do".

I saw a solution about Composite keys and stuff, but not I don't want to create a composite key just for that (and having to meddle with the fact of the composite key).

Is there something (which I'm maybe forgetting or simply don't know) like a `@OnInsert` for an entity field, which I can use and make my solution graceful.

Also, I do understand the fact that I can make a separate `@Query` to call `myfunc()` and set it before the entity goes to persist, but that eliminates the desire of having everything done clean (oh look, I generate @ID in one way, after which field B, which is similar, is done in a completely different manner...)